# AWS API Gateway Cognito Authorizer pass claims on integration-request with HTTP proxy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I have an express application running on an ECS instance, which is connected to the API Gateway. Users are authenticated by Cognito. I added the Cognito authorizer in front of the endpoints, and it works just fine. My problem is that I don't want to decode the token in the backend, and I want Cognito authorizer to pass the verified and already decoded claims into the request.

I am aware that from the integration request, using mapping templates, I can map the values and append them to the body of the request using following.

```
{
  "context": {
    "email": "$context.authorizer.claims.email"
  }
}
```

But I am using http proxy, and mapping template is not available when using gateway as proxy.

I was wondering if there is way to make this possible while using the api gateway as http proxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you can also append into params, query, or header by mapping a name to the value: `context.authorizer.claims.email`

Assuming I mapped it into header, within the app I can get this as `req.headers.{name}`